# why HTML page not loaded in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to open a html file in web view from the asset folder . when I place that html will on assest -> www directory it load in webview

```
 web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/a.html");
```

But when I place zip file on www in assest folder.First I copy the zip file and unzip the www folder .Then I load the html file 
on web file I am getting this error .The web page at `file:///data/data/com.example.test/files/www/a.html` might be temorarilydown?

When I check the data /data then goes to package name then files folder file is available in that .why I am getting this error ?i call like that

```
web.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(ATMSActivity.this.getFilesDir(),"www")).toString()+"/a.html");
```

already written

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler way, with a string  argument instead (assuming you really have a file in the Files Directory):

```
web.loadUrl((new File(ATMSActivity.this.getFilesDir(),"www")).getPath()+"/a.html");
```